# Custom button component always in a disabled state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my current code for a `Button` component I am building for my web app.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    fontFamily: 'Nunito, sans-serif',
    textTransform: 'none',
    padding: '0.5rem 1rem'
  },
})

export default ({
  variant,
  onClick,
  fullWidth,
  disabled,
  color,
  size,
  icon,
  disableElevation,
  children,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <Button
      variant={variant}
      onClick={onClick}
      fullWidth={fullWidth}
      disabled={disabled}
      color={color}
      size={size}
      classes={classes}
      startIcon={icon}
      disableElevation
      {...otherProps}
    >
      {children}
    </Button>
  )
}

Button.propTypes = {
  variant: PropTypes.oneOf(["text", "outlined", "contained"]),
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  fullWidth: PropTypes.bool,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  color: PropTypes.oneOf(['primary', 'secondary']).isRequired,
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(["small", "medium", "large"]),
  startIcon: PropTypes.node,
  disableElevation: PropTypes.bool
};

Button.defaultProps = {
  variant: "contained",
  fullWidth: false,
  disabled: false,
  color: "primary",
  size: "medium",
  disableElevation: true
}
```

When I load the button component in my app, in all the places where I am calling the button, the button all seem to be in the disabled state, and the only way they are not is if I explicitly add `disable={false}` on each button component. Any idea why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to the fact that in pure HTML a button is disabled even if it has its disabled attribute set to "false", for example

```
<button disabled="false">test</button>
```

...will render a disabled button. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Button for more informations on disabled attribute. "disabled" on button element is a boolean attribute, its presence means true, and values are not allowed : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#Boolean_Attributes.

[image]

In React/JSX you need to set the disabled attribute to undefined, so the attribute is not rendered. You can test that here :

[image: Edit Input disabled attribute]

I'm not sure if you encountered this problem but it may be a good lead.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the name of the disabled property in the Button component. Saying "disabled={disabled}" is the same as "**disabled={true}** or just **disabled**". So you could try naming disabled to something else. Let say;

```
             <Button
                variant={variant}
                onClick={onClick}
                fullWidth={fullWidth}
                disabled={isDisabled}
                color={color}
                size={size}
                classes={classes}
                startIcon={icon}
                disableElevation
                {...otherProps}
                >
                {children}
            </Button>
```